# Climate data from stations in Canada

Tags: api, weather, canada

Does anyone know of data available via an API for climate stations in Canada. NOAA has a nice API interface for US stations (http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2), and does have data for non-US stations, but not things that I want. I need 30 yr averages - which are only available from NOAA for US stations.

You can use a web interface to Canadian climate data here http://climate.weather.gc.ca/, but I am looking for API access.

UPDATE: found this http://data.gc.ca/eng/access-our-application-programming-interface-api - which says they are using the CKAN platform, but there are no docs basically on how to use it - maybe someone has?

Comment: Do you want to use the API regularly or only once to download the data? If the second is the case, you can try to contact with them and ask about the data. Most of the times, you have positive answers.

Comment: I do want to use the API for a research problem I have now, but also for making R software for others to use, so definitely the API

Answer (score 4):

The CKAN API is documented here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html.

Comment: Thanks. Was aware of the CKAN docs, but I'll look at them again